# Не работает проверка на категории WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Мне нужно проверять категорию и все вложенные категории, если запись принадлежит одной из них (главной или дочерней) то выводить один шаблон иначе другой.

Если делаю обычную проверку, она работает, но как только пишу `elseif` или `else` - перестает работать. Я в php слаб, может допустил ошибку, но вроде нет.

Вот мой код:

```
<?php if ( in_category( 5 ) || post_is_in_descendant_category( 5 ) || in_category( 0 ) || post_is_in_descendant_category( 0 ) )  { ?>
    // Здесь все "фрукты"
<?php } elseif ( in_category( 174 ) || post_is_in_descendant_category( 174 ) ) { ?>
Каталог
<?php } ?>
```